Error when using csquotes in "section" together with "hyperref" and double characters
I found a really weird behavior, and I can only guess why this is happening.
If I "enquote" (csquotes) something that starts with two identical characters in a section header AND use hyperref I get the error:
! Argument of \csq@pdf@quote@ii has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.19 \section{Foo Bar \enquote{AA}}

I don't know if this has something to do with expansion or kerning, but it seems pretty weird to me. Anything I can do about this? When the "double" character is not at the start everything is fine.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}

%Hyperref
\usepackage{hyperref}
 
 
\begin{document}
\section{Foo Bar \enquote{AA}}
\end{document}

EDIT: fix typos

Note that it is often best to make it as simple as possible, for example to remove anyhing KOMA related, just in case KOMA mattered (it does not I get the same error with article). You can also boil it down to only csquotes plus hyperref

your mwe is not an example. It not even load csquotes.

@UlrikeFischer I edited the example, as mentioned in the comment before, and it contains csquotes and hyperref. So perhaps you were checking in the exact moment i did the edit. But the example before was complete and the one now also is.

It's a bug in csquotes: if I modify two definitions to have \if*#1 instead of \if#1*, the run is successful.
The \if#1* test is obviously wrong: with \tracingmacros=1 I get
\enquote #1->\if #1*\relax \expandafter \@firstoftwo \else \expandafter \@secon
doftwo \fi {\csq@pdf@quote@ii } {\csq@pdf@quote@i {#1}}
#1<-AA

but clearly the macro is supposed to check if there's a leading *.
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{csquotes}
 
%Hyperref
\usepackage{hyperref}

% fix the bugs
\makeatletter
\long\def\csq@pdf@quote#1{%
  \if*#1\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {\csq@pdf@quote@ii}
    {\csq@pdf@quote@i{#1}}}
\long\def\csq@pdf@fquote#1{%
  \if*#1\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {\expandafter\csq@pdf@quote@ii\@gobble}
    {\csq@pdf@quote@i}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Foo Bar \enquote{AA}}

\end{document}


Note: the definition of \enquote that's shown in the tracing message is the one used when bookmarks are being prepared.
